# How to properly set state of an object on different form inputs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following code for my "BookForm" component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Book } from '../interfaces';

interface AddBookFormProps {
  isVisible: boolean;
  toggleVisibility: () => void;
}

export const AddBookForm: React.FC<AddBookFormProps> = ({
  isVisible,
  toggleVisibility,
}) => {
  const [bookFormInput, setBookFormInput] = useState<Book>();

  const handleFormSubmit = () => {};

  return (
    <>
      {isVisible && (
        <div className="fixed right-1/3 bottom-1/4 h-2/3 w-1/3 border-4 bg-white border-slate-600 shadow-xl">
          <div className="flex justify-between bg-slate-400">
            <p className="text-3xl m-6">Add a new Book</p>
            <div className="h-16 w-16 m-3">
              <button onClick={toggleVisibility}>
                <img
                  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/OOjs_UI_icon_close.svg/1200px-OOjs_UI_icon_close.svg.png"
                  alt="close-button"
                  className="object-fit border border-slate-900 hover:border-white transition rounded-md"
                ></img>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-center">
            <form className="w-1/2 bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4 ">
              <label
                htmlFor="bookName"
                className="block text-gray-700 font-bold text-sm"
              >
                Book name:
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="bookName"
                placeholder="Book name"
                className="w-full border rounded-md border-slate-500 text-sm ml-1 pl-1"
                onChange={(e) =>
                  setBookFormInput((book) => (book?.bookName = e.target.value))
                }
              ></input>
              <label
                htmlFor="bookName"
                className="block text-gray-700 font-bold text-sm"
              >
                Book genre:
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="bookGenre"
                placeholder="Book genre"
                className="w-full border rounded-md border-slate-500 text-sm ml-1 pl-1"
              ></input>
              <label
                htmlFor="bookGenre"
                className="block text-gray-700 font-bold text-sm"
              >
                Page Count:
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="pageCount"
                placeholder="Page count"
                className="w-full border rounded-md border-slate-500 text-sm ml-1 pl-1"
              ></input>
              <label
                htmlFor="pageCount"
                className="block text-gray-700 font-bold text-sm"
              >
                Book author name:
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="bookAuthorName"
                placeholder="Book author name"
                className="w-full border rounded-md border-slate-500 text-sm ml-1 pl-1"
              ></input>
              <label
                htmlFor="bookAuthorName"
                className="block text-gray-700 font-bold text-sm"
              >
                Isbn Number:
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="isbnNumber"
                placeholder="Isbn Number"
                className="w-full border rounded-md border-slate-500 text-sm ml-1 pl-1"
              ></input>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

My question is: What would be the correct way to set state on each input, which would correspond to the correct "bookFormInput"'s property?

example

in "bookName" input, after changing set the bookFormInput.bookName to current value, and so on

Any ideas?

Comment: Tha's too much codes for a simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set id for each input - same as book property name:

```
<input type='text' id='bookName' onChange={handleValueChange} />
<input type='text' id='author' onChange={handleValueChange} />
```

And add generic values change handler:

```
const handleValueChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setBookFormInput((v) => ({ ...v, [e.target.id]: e.target.value }))
}
```

Moreover, better to have default values as empty strings in state:

```
const [bookFormInput, setBookFormInput] = useState<Book>({bookName: '', author: ''})
```

If you are not satisfied or your example is more complicated, you can use library like Formik.